# Angularjs ng-bind-html resize button to fit content size?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-bindings

Given list of texts with some FontAwesome icons, my controller need to pass that to template, and render each into button.

Example text:

```
'<i class="fa fa-hourglass fa-fw">Postpone'
```

My code:

```
<button ng-repeat="text in texts" type="button">[[text]]</button>
```

However it wont work as expected.

- `[[text]]` will escape any html
- `ng-bind-html` will fail to resize button after inserting text

What else can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

`<i>` tag is not closed properly, which will result in browser and/or $sanitize closing `</i>` at the end of text. `<i>` with some text in it still have size of font awesome, ng-bind-html nor button will know about text.

Valid example:

`'<i class="fa fa-hourglass fa-fw">`**`</i>`**`Postpone'`